# Impossible to import model_utils module in Django models.py

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, import, importerror

I follow the [official documentation of the django-model-utils model](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html) and I've just done `pip install django-model-utils` in my virtual environment.

However, VSCode indicates that `Import "model_utils.managers" could not be resolved` as shown below.

[VSCode error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxIel.png)

With `pip list` I've checked that the module is effectively installed.

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ --------
asgiref                  3.6.0
autopep8                 2.0.1
defusedxml               0.7.1
diff-match-patch         20200713
Django                   4.1.5
django-admin-rangefilter 0.9.0
django-extensions        3.2.1
django-import-export     3.1.0
django-model-utils       4.3.1
django-phonenumber-field 7.0.2
djangorestframework      3.14.0
et-xmlfile               1.1.0
import-export            0.3.1
MarkupPy                 1.14
odfpy                    1.4.1
openpyxl                 3.1.1
phonenumbers             8.13.4
Pillow                   9.4.0
pip                      22.0.2
pycodestyle              2.10.0
pytz                     2022.7.1
PyYAML                   6.0
setuptools               59.6.0
sqlparse                 0.4.3
tablib                   3.3.0
tomli                    2.0.1
xlrd                     2.0.1
```

And I've look that the folder exists with the right name and a `__init__.py` file as shown below.
[Screenshot of lib folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5312i.png)

How can I solve this please ?

Comment: Try restarting VSCode and reloading the Python interpreter. To reload the Python interpreter, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) and type "Python: Select Interpreter". Then, select the interpreter that corresponds to your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting VSCode and reloading the Python interpreter. To reload the Python interpreter, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) and type "Python: Select Interpreter". Then, select the interpreter that corresponds to your virtual environment.